# Is $f$ is onto ? True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group  and  $x \in G$.Define map  $f: G \to G$ by $f(x)=x^{-1}$

Now my question is that

Is  $f$ is onto ? True/false

**My attempt** : I think $f$ will  not onto because $\frac{1}{ x }\notin G$

Take $G= \mathbb{Z}$  and  $x = 2$   but $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}$ an abelian group? Under what operation? What is the inverse of 2 under this operation?

Comment: Presumably $x^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $x$ under the group operation for $G$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers under addition and inverse is $-2$

Comment: oks  i was thinking wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether $G$ is abelian or not, $f(x^{-1})=(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$, so $f$ is surjective.  That is, in a group every element has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

This map $f$ is always onto/surjective. Your example does not make any sense. If $\mathbb{Z}$ is your group under addition, then inverse of $2$ is -2, NOT $1/2.$

The reason why the map is always surjective is the following: for every element $x \in G$, there is another element namely $x^{-1} \in G.$

Another way: You just argue using the fact $ (x^{-1})^{-1}= x.$